# jQuery str.split does not works

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I'm sending a list(in python) as a response via server in an AJAX call.

The response is `[u"<select id = '1_level1'><option>Select Region </option><option>Asia / Pacific</option><option>North America</option></select>", u"<select id = '2_level1'><option>Select Region </option><option>Asia / Pacific</option><option>North America</option></select>"]`

When I use

```
success: function(result){

          $("#compare1").html(result.split(",")[0]);
```

It prints both the select option. How can I split the list ?

**Edited**

```
elif request.POST.has_key('compare_options'):

            #user_organization_id = 
            compare_id = request.POST.getlist('id[]')
            level1_options = Level1Detail.objects.filter(organization_id = 1) # change it with user_organization_id

            option = []

            for ids in compare_id:
                option_str = ""
                level1_options_str = "<option>Select Region </option>"
                for options in level1_options:
                    level1_options_str += "<option>"+options.level1_name+"</option>"
                option_str = "<select id = '"+ids+"level1'>" + level1_options_str + "</select>"
                option.append(option_str)

            print option


            return HttpResponse(option)
```

Comment: What has this to do with Python?

Comment: Why are you sending Python string and list representations instead of JSON data? Use the `json` module to send data for jQuery to work with natively instead of trying to parse Python literal values.

Comment: @user2799617: *at a guess* the OP is sending the `repr()` of a python list to JavaScript, and is figuring out how to parse that. A classical XY problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters- Can you please provide a demo?

Comment: @user1162512: `import json; json.dumps(yourlist)`.

Comment: I edited the question with my python code as well. I dont see adding json.dumps to my code. How can I make it work? Kindly help

Comment: @user1162512: is this Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a JSON response instead, using the [`json` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```py
import json

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(option), content_type="application/json")
```

In jQuery, make sure you tell it to receive JSON:

```js
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Comment: What is `success:success`? Should I write `success: function(result){

          $("#compare1").html(result.split(",")[0]);`

Comment: @user1162512: `success` is your success callback, yes. `result` will be a valid JavaScript list of strings.

Comment: If the content type is set to json, jQuery will usually be smart enough to automatically parse it as json, although stating it explicitly doesn't hurt.

Comment: @forivall: Indeed; I mostly put that in there because the OP didn't share the actual AJAX call code and you never know what datatype might be set there.